# Warn the user before session timeout in servlets and jsp with single configuration

Tags: java, spring, session, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am implementing a framework for web Projects(they used Servlet,Struts,Spring)
Default session timeout is defined in web.xml is 60 min.

if user is idle for 45 mins than I need to show a popup to user with message that Your session is going to be end by 15 min, Please click OK to continue.

with out using cookies is there any other way to implement please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript with timeout function set for 45 mins. On javascript timeout warn the user with JS popup. On clicking OK simply send server request using Ajax to extend session for 60 more mins. Also reset JS timeout function.

Cheers
SonyM

Comment: using {pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval} in jsp ?